# Partial Fractions in Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

[image]

[image]

I did my very best to do and redo by equation over and over, yet I cant get beyond this result. I'm not sure if the answer given at the back of my book is wrong or I am. Please help!!!!!!!!!.

Comment: The limit should give you $1/3(ln (2)+ln(2))$

Comment: Basically you were good up to the very last line

Comment: but how did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: Remark that $\frac{2B-1}{B+2}=\frac{2-\frac{1}{B}}{1+\frac{2}{B}}$ converges toward $2$ when $B$ goes to infinity so that at the limit (like it is written in Joel's comment) you have $1/3(\ln(2)+\ln(2))$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{B\to \infty}\frac{2B-1}{B+2}=2$.  Similarly, $\lim\limits_{B\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{2B-1}{B+2}\right)=\ln2$.  So... we have the $\ln 2$ that came from this half, and then we have *a second* $\ln 2$ on the far right which can be combined with the first to be $2\ln 2$.  Then, we apply the factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ which was being multiplied to the entire integral to get $\frac{2}{3}\ln 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until you have $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{b}\frac{2}{2x+1}-\frac{1}{x+2}dx$$Your solution was correct.Then you would get$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{3}(\ln(\frac{2b+1}{b+2})+\ln2)$$ So a nuisance is the plus instead of minus. But that's not what changed your answer, I think you  forgot to add the $\ln2$ resulting from the lower bound in the integral. If you add both of the $\ln2$s, you would get the desired answer, $\frac{2\ln2}{3}$